# Change label size of Cluster Dendrogram in R 3.01

Tags: r, size, label, hclust

Has anybody found a workaround to the apparent bug in R 3 which prohibits changing the label size on a Cluster Dendrogram?

The following code used to work fine before updating R to 3.01 (prior version was 2.15 I think):

```
plot(hclust, labels = data[, 1], cex = 0.3)
```

Now there is no change to label size when altering the `cex` argument.

Comment: Download patched version of R 3.0.1, bug has already been fixed http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/NEWS

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could set the `cex` parameter using the `par()` function before the call to `plot()`.  For example:

```
# example from ?hclust
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

# default label size
plot(hc, xlab="xlab", ylab="ylab", main="main", sub="")

# reduced label size
par(cex=0.3, mar=c(5, 8, 4, 1))
plot(hc, xlab="", ylab="", main="", sub="", axes=FALSE)
par(cex=1)
title(xlab="xlab", ylab="ylab", main="main")
axis(2)
```