# Suppress leaf labels in dendrograms

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, axis-labels, dendrogram

I'm not an expert in cluster analysis and thus not really familiar with all the "special" contributed packages out there. Hence, I just used base routines as the did [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html) for a quick example I was asked to produce.

The problem is that my dataset has roughly 7800 observations and thus the leaf labels are by far too manifold and clutter up the whole x-axis. So, how can I suppress the plotting of the labels? I'm guessing there must be some "exotic" parameter accessible via `par()` that controls this?

Comment: Would be nice to see why this Q got downvoted? BTW, Jonathan noticed something in a hclust plotting function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232178/change-label-size-of-cluster-dendrogram-in-r-3-01

Comment: Sorry guys, totally missed that! Usually, I *do* read the help files ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the help for `hclust`

```
?hclust
```

There you will see an explanation of the `labels` argument: "*If `labels = FALSE` no labels at all are plotted.*"  Using the example from the help file,

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc, labels=FALSE)
```